# How do i put the button in the bottom left? (vaadin)

Tags: button, layout, vaadin

Ive red the vaadin documentation but i didnt find anything useful. i have created 2 buttons and right now, theyre in the middle vertically and horizontally, but i wanna put them in the bottom left. I dont really know how cause i havnt find anything useful on stackoverflow neither. (im a beginner)

my teacher told me to try this:
this.setJustifyContentMode(FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.CENTER); // Put content at the bottom left horizontally.
this.setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER); // Put content at the bottom left vertically.

this still didnt work tho.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking to place the buttons inside a layout. You can find the documentation and code sample for the latest Vaadin version here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/vertical-layout#horizontal-alignment

It'd look something like this:

```
VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
layout.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.END);
layout.add(new Button("Button 1"));
layout.add(new Button("Button 2"));
```